# Не работает кнопка в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ide

У меня тут не работает кнопка AVD-manager в Android Studio. Как её включить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте закрыть студию и окрыть ее в режиме администратора

Comment: Попробовал, не работает

Comment: ctr+shift+A наберите AVD - открывает?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290134/android-studio-avd-manager-button-is-disabled

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо большое